# Listbox display from a form into a list C#

Tags: c#, forms, list, listbox

i am having a problem with a listbox, i have to add from a form into a list, and after that into a listbox, i already tried:

```
list <string> myList = new list<string>
Add("Blabla");
listbox1.DataSources=myList;
```

But that is not what i seek, i wish to add from a list of type `List <student>` and it doesen't work. Thank you

Comment: Please defined what `it doesn't work` means - if you have error, then specify error details, if you have not expected result, specify what result you have and what is expected result

Comment: it seems you need a `DataGridView` or `ListView` not Listbox.

Comment: First the declaration is wrong,                                    list <string> myList = new list<string>();
myList.Add("Blabla");

Answer (score 0):

use data bind

```
listbox1.DataSource = myList;
listbox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: It's not required in WinForms

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();
int i = 0;

foreach (var student in studentList)
{
   myList.Insert(i, student.Name);
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First the declaration is wrong

```
list <string> myList = new list<string>(); 
myList.Add("Blabla");
```